# ¿Como generar numeración especifica en una tabla?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen día ....

Tengo este escript:

```
select   #vt.Conteo Conteo,   EnfMed.Campo Campo, EnfMed.Tabla,
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY EnfMed.Tabla order by EnfMed.Conteo) NroCase
from ##ValoresPorTabla #vt 
outer apply
(
    select Conteo, Campo ,   Tabla, NroCampo,  
    ROW_NUMBER() over (  partition by Tabla order by  Conteo, NroCampo ) Row,  
    ROW_NUMBER() over(order by (select null)) Nro           
    from
    (
        select '' Conteo, Campo ,  'enf' Tabla, ROW_NUMBER() over (  order by  Campo) NroCampo
        from TablaCampoInformes
        where Tabla ='Enfermedad_Paciente_FichaIOS' and Campo <> 'Id_FichaIOS'
        union all 
        select Conteo, Campo, data.Tabla, NroCampo 
        from ##ValoresPorTabla #vt 
        cross apply 
        (
            select Campo ,  'med' Tabla, ROW_NUMBER() over (  order by  Campo) NroCampo
            from TablaCampoInformes
            where Tabla ='Medicamento_Administrado' and Campo <> 'Id_FichaIOS'
        )data
        where #vt.Tabla ='Medicamento_Administrado'
        )x 
)EnfMed  where #vt.Tabla = 'Medicamento_Administrado'
order by  Conteo, Nro
```

El cual devuelve los datos ordenados de la siguiente manera ...

```html
Conteo      Campo                                 Tabla NroCase                                                               
----------- ------------------------------------- ----- --------------------
1           Fecha_Enfermedad                      enf   1
1           Id_Enfermedad                         enf   1
1           Id_Tipo_Enfermedad                    enf   1
1           Fecha_Fin                             med   1
1           Fecha_Inicio                          med   1
1           Id_Medicamento                        med   1
1           Id_Medicamento_Administrado           med   1
1           Id_TipoMedicamento                    med   1
1           Id_ViaAdministracion                  med   1
1           Fecha_Fin                             med   2
1           Fecha_Inicio                          med   2
1           Id_Medicamento                        med   2
1           Id_Medicamento_Administrado           med   2
1           Id_TipoMedicamento                    med   2
1           Id_ViaAdministracion                  med   2
1           Fecha_Fin                             med   3
1           Fecha_Inicio                          med   3
1           Id_Medicamento                        med   3
1           Id_Medicamento_Administrado           med   3
1           Id_TipoMedicamento                    med   3
1           Id_ViaAdministracion                  med   3
1           Fecha_Fin                             med   4
1           Fecha_Inicio                          med   4
1           Id_Medicamento                        med   4
1           Id_Medicamento_Administrado           med   4
1           Id_TipoMedicamento                    med   4
1           Id_ViaAdministracion                  med   4
1           Fecha_Fin                             med   5
1           Fecha_Inicio                          med   5
1           Id_Medicamento                        med   5
1           Id_Medicamento_Administrado           med   5
1           Id_TipoMedicamento                    med   5
1           Id_ViaAdministracion                  med   5
2           Fecha_Enfermedad                      enf   1
2           Id_Enfermedad                         enf   1
2           Id_Tipo_Enfermedad                    enf   1
2           Fecha_Fin                             med   1
2           Fecha_Inicio                          med   1
2           Id_Medicamento                        med   1
2           Id_Medicamento_Administrado           med   1
2           Id_TipoMedicamento                    med   1
2           Id_ViaAdministracion                  med   1
2           Fecha_Fin                             med   2
2           Fecha_Inicio                          med   2
2           Id_Medicamento                        med   2
2           Id_Medicamento_Administrado           med   2
2           Id_TipoMedicamento                    med   2
2           Id_ViaAdministracion                  med   2
2           Fecha_Fin                             med   3
2           Fecha_Inicio                          med   3
2           Id_Medicamento                        med   3
2           Id_Medicamento_Administrado           med   3
2           Id_TipoMedicamento                    med   3
2           Id_ViaAdministracion                  med   3
2           Fecha_Fin                             med   4
2           Fecha_Inicio                          med   4
2           Id_Medicamento                        med   4
2           Id_Medicamento_Administrado           med   4
2           Id_TipoMedicamento                    med   4
2           Id_ViaAdministracion                  med   4
2           Fecha_Fin                             med   5
2           Fecha_Inicio                          med   5
2           Id_Medicamento                        med   5
2           Id_Medicamento_Administrado           med   5
2           Id_TipoMedicamento                    med   5
2           Id_ViaAdministracion                  med   5
3           Fecha_Enfermedad                      enf   1
3           Id_Enfermedad                         enf   1
3           Id_Tipo_Enfermedad                    enf   1
3           Fecha_Fin                             med   1
3           Fecha_Inicio                          med   1
3           Id_Medicamento                        med   1
3           Id_Medicamento_Administrado           med   1
3           Id_TipoMedicamento                    med   1
3           Id_ViaAdministracion                  med   1
3           Fecha_Fin                             med   2
3           Fecha_Inicio                          med   2
3           Id_Medicamento                        med   2
3           Id_Medicamento_Administrado           med   2
3           Id_TipoMedicamento                    med   2
3           Id_ViaAdministracion                  med   2
3           Fecha_Fin                             med   3
3           Fecha_Inicio                          med   3
3           Id_Medicamento                        med   3
3           Id_Medicamento_Administrado           med   3
3           Id_TipoMedicamento                    med   3
3           Id_ViaAdministracion                  med   3
3           Fecha_Fin                             med   4
3           Fecha_Inicio                          med   4
3           Id_Medicamento                        med   4
3           Id_Medicamento_Administrado           med   4
3           Id_TipoMedicamento                    med   4
3           Id_ViaAdministracion                  med   4
3           Fecha_Fin                             med   5
3           Fecha_Inicio                          med   5
3           Id_Medicamento                        med   5
3           Id_Medicamento_Administrado           med   5
3           Id_TipoMedicamento                    med   5
3           Id_ViaAdministracion                  med   5
4           Fecha_Enfermedad                      enf   1
4           Id_Enfermedad                         enf   1
4           Id_Tipo_Enfermedad                    enf   1
4           Fecha_Fin                             med   1
4           Fecha_Inicio                          med   1
4           Id_Medicamento                        med   1
4           Id_Medicamento_Administrado           med   1
4           Id_TipoMedicamento                    med   1
4           Id_ViaAdministracion                  med   1
4           Fecha_Fin                             med   2
4           Fecha_Inicio                          med   2
4           Id_Medicamento                        med   2
4           Id_Medicamento_Administrado           med   2
4           Id_TipoMedicamento                    med   2
4           Id_ViaAdministracion                  med   2
4           Fecha_Fin                             med   3
4           Fecha_Inicio                          med   3
4           Id_Medicamento                        med   3
4           Id_Medicamento_Administrado           med   3
4           Id_TipoMedicamento                    med   3
4           Id_ViaAdministracion                  med   3
4           Fecha_Fin                             med   4
4           Fecha_Inicio                          med   4
4           Id_Medicamento                        med   4
4           Id_Medicamento_Administrado           med   4
4           Id_TipoMedicamento                    med   4
4           Id_ViaAdministracion                  med   4
4           Fecha_Fin                             med   5
4           Fecha_Inicio                          med   5
4           Id_Medicamento                        med   5
4           Id_Medicamento_Administrado           med   5
4           Id_TipoMedicamento                    med   5
4           Id_ViaAdministracion                  med   5
5           Fecha_Enfermedad                      enf   1
5           Id_Enfermedad                         enf   1
5           Id_Tipo_Enfermedad                    enf   1
5           Fecha_Fin                             med   1
5           Fecha_Inicio                          med   1
5           Id_Medicamento                        med   1
5           Id_Medicamento_Administrado           med   1
5           Id_TipoMedicamento                    med   1
5           Id_ViaAdministracion                  med   1
5           Fecha_Fin                             med   2
5           Fecha_Inicio                          med   2
5           Id_Medicamento                        med   2
5           Id_Medicamento_Administrado           med   2
5           Id_TipoMedicamento                    med   2
5           Id_ViaAdministracion                  med   2
5           Fecha_Fin                             med   3
5           Fecha_Inicio                          med   3
5           Id_Medicamento                        med   3
5           Id_Medicamento_Administrado           med   3
5           Id_TipoMedicamento                    med   3
5           Id_ViaAdministracion                  med   3
5           Fecha_Fin                             med   4
5           Fecha_Inicio                          med   4
5           Id_Medicamento                        med   4
5           Id_Medicamento_Administrado           med   4
5           Id_TipoMedicamento                    med   4
5           Id_ViaAdministracion                  med   4
5           Fecha_Fin                             med   5
5           Fecha_Inicio                          med   5
5           Id_Medicamento                        med   5
5           Id_Medicamento_Administrado           med   5
5           Id_TipoMedicamento                    med   5
5           Id_ViaAdministracion                  med   5
```

el ordenamiento que se puede apreciar, es el siguiente:

Cuando la columna Tabla cambia el Contador NroCase se reinicia, esta parte esta bien, sin embargo, yo necesito que los registros con valores: Fecha_Enfermedad ,Id_Enfermedad, Id_Tipo_Enfermedad incrementen su numeración en 1 cada vez que el contador de la columna  NroCase cambie, pero que los demás registros mantengan la numeración actual. Tal como muestro :

```html
Conteo      Campo                                       Tabla Nro        NroCase
----------- ------------------------------------------- ----- ---------- --------------------
1           Fecha_Enfermedad                            enf   1          1
1           Id_Enfermedad                               enf   2          1
1           Id_Tipo_Enfermedad                          enf   3          1
1           Fecha_Fin                                   med   4          1
1           Fecha_Inicio                                med   5          1
1           Id_Medicamento                              med   6          1
1           Id_Medicamento_Administrado                 med   7          1
1           Id_TipoMedicamento                          med   8          1
1           Id_ViaAdministracion                        med   9          1
1           Fecha_Fin                                   med   10         2
1           Fecha_Inicio                                med   11         2
1           Id_Medicamento                              med   12         2
1           Id_Medicamento_Administrado                 med   13         2
1           Id_TipoMedicamento                          med   14         2
1           Id_ViaAdministracion                        med   15         2
1           Fecha_Fin                                   med   16         3
1           Fecha_Inicio                                med   17         3
1           Id_Medicamento                              med   18         3
1           Id_Medicamento_Administrado                 med   19         3
1           Id_TipoMedicamento                          med   20         3
1           Id_ViaAdministracion                        med   21         3
1           Fecha_Fin                                   med   22         4
1           Fecha_Inicio                                med   23         4
1           Id_Medicamento                              med   24         4
1           Id_Medicamento_Administrado                 med   25         4
1           Id_TipoMedicamento                          med   26         4
1           Id_ViaAdministracion                        med   27         4
1           Fecha_Fin                                   med   28         5
1           Fecha_Inicio                                med   29         5
1           Id_Medicamento                              med   30         5
1           Id_Medicamento_Administrado                 med   31         5
1           Id_TipoMedicamento                          med   32         5
1           Id_ViaAdministracion                        med   33         5
2           Fecha_Enfermedad                            enf   1          2
2           Id_Enfermedad                               enf   2          2
2           Id_Tipo_Enfermedad                          enf   3          2
2           Fecha_Fin                                   med   4          1
2           Fecha_Inicio                                med   5          1
2           Id_Medicamento                              med   6          1
2           Id_Medicamento_Administrado                 med   7          1
2           Id_TipoMedicamento                          med   8          1
2           Id_ViaAdministracion                        med   9          1
2           Fecha_Fin                                   med   10         2
2           Fecha_Inicio                                med   11         2
2           Id_Medicamento                              med   12         2
2           Id_Medicamento_Administrado                 med   13         2
2           Id_TipoMedicamento                          med   14         2
2           Id_ViaAdministracion                        med   15         2
2           Fecha_Fin                                   med   16         3
2           Fecha_Inicio                                med   17         3
2           Id_Medicamento                              med   18         3
2           Id_Medicamento_Administrado                 med   19         3
2           Id_TipoMedicamento                          med   20         3
2           Id_ViaAdministracion                        med   21         3
2           Fecha_Fin                                   med   22         4
2           Fecha_Inicio                                med   23         4
2           Id_Medicamento                              med   24         4
2           Id_Medicamento_Administrado                 med   25         4
2           Id_TipoMedicamento                          med   26         4
2           Id_ViaAdministracion                        med   27         4
2           Fecha_Fin                                   med   28         5
2           Fecha_Inicio                                med   29         5
2           Id_Medicamento                              med   30         5
2           Id_Medicamento_Administrado                 med   31         5
2           Id_TipoMedicamento                          med   32         5
2           Id_ViaAdministracion                        med   33         5
```

Como puedo lograr esto ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una posible solución es que crees un procedimiento almacenado.

Pasos

1. Utiliza la consulta que ya tienes para cargar una tabla temporal, previamente aplicando truncate;
2. Luego a través de un cursor iteras e implementas la lógica:

> "yo necesito que los registros con valores: Fecha_Enfermedad
>   ,Id_Enfermedad, Id_Tipo_Enfermedad incrementen su numeración en 1 cada
>   vez que el contador de la columna NroCase cambie, pero que los demás
>   registros mantengan la numeración actual."

Actualizando en cada iteracción la columna conteo, para solucionarlo puedes usar contadores para determinar el número de apariciones o cambios de los valores que requieres respecto al campo NroCase.

Espero haberte ayudado